# Why I get a mismatched types error when I try to associate a value to a variable to match a dyn parameter?

Tags: rust

I am trying to initiate a struct which is:

```
struct Task {
    future: Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>>,
    executor: channel::Sender<Arc<Task>>,
}
```

It works fine when I do like this:

```
    fn spawn<F>(future: F, sender: &channel::Sender<Arc<Task>>)
    where
        F: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'static,
    {
        let task = Arc::new(Task {
            future: Mutex::new(Box::pin(future)),
            executor: sender.clone(),
        });
        sender.send(task).unwrap();
    }
```

However, when I try to associate future to a variable first, the mismatched type error occurs:

```
    fn spawn<F>(future: F, sender: &channel::Sender<Arc<Task>>)
    where
        F: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'static,
    {
        let future = Mutex::new(Box::pin(future));
        let task = Arc::new(Task {
            future,
            executor: sender.clone(),
        });
        sender.send(task).unwrap();
    }
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\bin\test.rs:76:13
   |
70 |     fn spawn<F>(future: F, sender: &channel::Sender<Arc<Task>>)
   |              - this type parameter
...
76 |             future,
   |             ^^^^^^ expected `Mutex<Pin<Box<...>>>`, found `Mutex<Pin<Box<F>>>`   
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::sync::Mutex<Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Future<Output = ()> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>>`
              found struct `std::sync::Mutex<Pin<Box<F>>>`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
```

the error is fixed after I specify the type of future explicitly:

```
let future: Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>> = Mutex::new(Box::pin(future));
```

Why did this happen? Is it because the compiler can't infer dyn types automatically?

Comment: Please always post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't try to coerce the `Pin<Box<F>>` to `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>`: it doesn't believe it is needed when it sees this expression. It doesn't have any hint that a `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>` is expected. It's only after you construct the `Mutex` that you see you expected a `Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future>>>`, and tries to coerce the `Mutex<Pin<Box<F>>>` to that.

But coercions are not transitive: the fact that `Pin<Box<F>>` can be coerced to `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>` doesn't mean that `Mutex<Pin<Box<F>>>` can be coerced to `Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future>>>`. So the compiler fails with the coercion, and reports an error.

You just need to hint the compiler to coerce the type in the right place. One way to do this is as you did; another is to use `as`:

```rust
    fn spawn<F>(future: F, sender: &channel::Sender<Arc<Task>>)
    where
        F: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'static,
    {
        let future = Mutex::new(Box::pin(future) as Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>);
        let task = Arc::new(Task {
            future,
            executor: sender.clone(),
        });
        sender.send(task).unwrap();
    }
```

Comment: I can’t test locally right now, but usually for coercing you can get away with `as _`, as that gives the compiler the proper hint.

Comment: @PatientPenguin Yeah you're right, that should work too.